# jquery plugin appending external librarys are not reconized (crypto-js,criptico)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cryptojs

I am building a jquery plugin im using this code to include external files:

```
if(!$("script[src*='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js']").length){

        var myScript =  "<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js'></script>";

        $(myScript).appendTo("head");

    }
```

It works great with promise js , but when i try this with crypto-js and cryptico scripts it  does append the files to the html but for some reason i can't access the imported scripts.  this is the error i get :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lib' of undefined

Comment: Why should you append to head?

Comment: where else? i changed it to body it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
if($("script[src*='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js']").length < 1){
    $.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js');
}
```

Comment: Thanks it wroked.

Comment: Can you describe what the issue was?